# How to add product to cart using laravel with angular

Tags: angular, laravel

please i need help on laravel with angular 9, i was trying to add a product to cart from the frontend to backend which is laravel using api route. when i clicked on add to cart button, nothing was adding to cart, below are my codes:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Product;

use App\Cart;

class ProductController extends Controller
{

    public function addToCart(Request $request, $id){
         $product = Product::find($id);

         $cart = session()->get('cart');
        // if cart is empty then this the first product
        if(!$cart) {

            $cart = [
                    $id => [
                        "name" => $product->name,
                        "quantity" => 1,
                        "price" => $product->price,
                        "photo" => $product->image
                    ]
            ];

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return response()->json(['success'=> 'Product has been added to cart']);
        }

         // if cart not empty then check if this product exist then increment quantity
         if(isset($cart[$id])) {

            $cart[$id]['quantity']++;

            session()->put('cart', $cart);

            return response()->json(['success'=> 'Product has been added to cart']);

        }

        // if item not exist in cart then add to cart with quantity = 1
        $cart[$id] = [
            "name" => $product->name,
            "quantity" => 1,
            "price" => $product->price,
            "photo" => $product->image
        ];

        session()->put('cart', $cart);

        return response()->json(['success'=> 'Product has been added to cart']);
    }
}
```

please help.

Answer (score 0):

Session store data for only one request you can push your data into Cache. please follow this link to store data in cache https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/cache